# PHP variable from external php file

Tags: php, variables, global-variables

I've three files:

```
index.php 
/include/conf.php 
/include/database.php
```

`conf.php` contains variables to connect to the database.
`database.php` includes `conf.php` and has a function to return an entire table as array. `index.php` includes `/include/database.php` and calls `get_table('users');`

`XDebug` says me that `$db_host, $db_user, $db_pass and $db_name` are not defined.

How can I pass the Database related variables through external files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP [Define](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_define.asp) function

eg:

```
define("db_host", "localhost");
```

Or Use

PHP [Session](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) variable

Answer (score 1):

If you are using these variables in a function, use **global** like

```
global $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name;
```

and then you can use these variables. For details, [see here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 0):

It's not normal, I use include and I can call variables of the included page !
Try to include both files in the index.php !!

Answer (score 0):

Define variable as constant in conf.php and then use this variable anywhere include conf.php

Answer (score 0):

use `include(*path to php page*);`

or `include_once();`

or `require();`